# How to include recipe for another image in Yocto

Tags: yocto, recipe, connman

I would like to include the following recipe in a non quemu image through a bbappend file. How do I override the 
SRC_URI_append_quemuall?

https://github.com/ExorEmbedded/yocto-poky/blob/exorint/meta/recipes-connectivity/connman/connman-conf.bb

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want those two config files in your image, for a non-qemu machine, the best would be to add a bbappend in your own layer, and just copy the two SRC_URI lines there. And while copying, remove _append_qemuall.

Though, it's quite likely that you also should supply your own versions of those configuration files in that layer.

Answer (score 0):

copy your recipe name and open vi meta-yogurt/recipes-images/your-image-name

add recipename  recipename-dev

if you have .so , .a libs for rootfs then addd " recipename-staticdev " also